# Problema con la creación de login en symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy tratando de hacer un login en un proyecto symfony mediante el comando make:auth pero siempre me saca este error:

Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Security\InteractiveSecurityHelper::guessEntryPoint() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\wamp64\www\PHP2020\InstaFace\vendor\symfony\maker-bundle\src\Maker\MakeAuthenticator.php on line 142

MI clase User ya está configurada implementando los métodos de la UserInterface, al igual que mi archivo security.yaml ya tiene el provider configurado. Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme, llevo un tiempo demasiado largo enfrascado en este problema

Este es mi archivo security.yaml:

security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Y esta es mi clase User:
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: creo que has puesto el security donde debería ir la implementación de la clase User.